# make a list of a list out of the header from a csv file

Tags: csv, computer-science

I want to put the header of the csv file in a nested list.
It should have ann output like this:
[[name], [age], [""], [""]]

how can I do this without reading the line again (I am not allowed to and I also am not allowed to use csv module and pandas (all imports except os are forbidden))

[image: my csv file looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

Just map the item of the list to list. Check below

```
def value_to_list(tlist):
    l=len(tlist)
    for i in range(l):
        tlist[i]=[tlist[i]]
    return tlist

headers=[]
with open(r"D:\my_projects\DemoProject\test.csv","r") as file :
    headers = value_to_list(file.readline().split(","))
```

test.csv file is "col1,col2,col3"
output :

```
> python -u "run.py"
[['col1'], ['col2'], ['col3']]
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sadly I am not allowed to use map...

Comment: You won't need any other import for it, but if you still don't want to use map, then we can achieve same using function. Will update my code.

Comment: that would be great

Comment: In this project, I am only allowed to open the file once. Could you give me a hint how I can manage that?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yxppgg5o6V0hRni2cHJTN6tAnAbE1SDU/view?usp=share_link
Check the code in above link. It should work

Comment: Thank you so much. the output looks like that now.[['name'], [' age'], [' '], ['\n']]. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Could you maybe explain how or if  I can reuse the function to creat lists of out of the file?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you need here. Could you please ask another question with all the details?

Comment: So I have a file with csv values. I need to make sure that the list of the header does not contain an empty list. that is the reason why I tried to code it with

Comment: header_list = []
headline = str(my_list[0])
header_strip = (headline).strip
 = str(header_strip).split(",")
header.append(header_split)

Comment: but the problem is that I constantly get an error that the str object has no attribute...

Comment: Can you post first few lines of your input file along with header?

Comment: sure. wait a sec.